# Application supported in iPhone 4 and 5 without changing storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an existing working app, created on Xcode 5, built and designed for iPhone 5 , 5s…( iPhone 4 inches). 
 if i am to make it supported to iPhone 4 (3.5 inches) all the design would be messed up… should i create a mew storyboard just for iPhone 4/4s and in the main page test whether it's an iPhone 4 or 5 and load the appropriate storyboard? or is there any feature that could just make all the design fit the screen of an iPhone 4 ?? rearranging all of the design could take lots and lots of time
Many thanks

Comment: Just learn AutoLayout and apply it to your code and/or storyboard. Storyboard should be always one for all iPhones, and another one if you also support iPad. But AutoLayout will take care of different dimensions of the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While auto layout is a really great thing ! and apple really helped a lot of developers with it , but in my case the solution was to handle it manually by creating two storyboards :) but i would like to recommend auto layout to all developers :)

Answer (score 2):

Auto Layouts is a great thing. I would start with this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Once you implement auto layouts you can see see how your screen looks like for specific iPhone version even without running the app. You can just switch the view in storyboard by clicking "Apply form factor" button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Autolayout`to manage the screen size